# Karate not allowing invalid Json syntax

Tags: javascript, karate

I am using a json request and as part of negative testing, I am making it as invalid as below.
I have removed the comma at the end of plancode line and I am expecting this request to go to server and show the error response from server.The problem is it is giving me syntax error in Karate as

> net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token "

It is working fine through SOAP UI. Need help here !

```
def user =

{
"requesterID": "test1",
"clientTraceLevel": 4,
"application": "ABC",
"planCode": "newcode"
"planEffDate":"12/3/2018",
"status": "b"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text` data type:

```
* text user =
"""
{
"requesterID": "test1",
"clientTraceLevel": 4,
"application": "ABC",
"planCode": "newcode"
"planEffDate":"12/3/2018",
"status": "b"
}
"""
```

Note that you may need to force the right `Content-Type` header in this case, please read the docs on how to do so.

Comment: Wonderful ...thanks it is working fine with your suggestion