# How to handle with duplicate object in karate

Tags: object, duplicates, karate

I am expecting duplicate object to be parsed and post in a request for testing a negative scenario, But karate is sorting and removing the duplicate object

"Test": {
"number": "12344",
"number": "12344"
}

I want both of the "number" to be present after karate parse the json, How can I achieve that

Comment: Duplicate keys [are not valid in ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-json.parse). If you want to use them you have to get a custom parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying a negative scenario. Then you have to bypass the Karate JSON parser. Use the `text` syntax or use a string (note the single-quotes): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#text

Here is an example:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/post'
* request '{ "Test": { "number": "12344", "number": "12344" } }'
* method post
```

See this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014394/143475