# karate is cutting of same names fieldnames?

Tags: karate, testautomationfx

i am wondering if karate is doing somehow optimization stuff,
looking into json body and makes it more rightful ? :-)

Scenario:

```
Given path 'blubb'
And header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ blabla
And url bimbambom
And request { "properties": {"var1": '8.bg', "var1": '9.bg'}}
When method POST
```

In the cucumber report i see this:
...
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

```
{"properties":{"var1":"9.bg"}}
```

...

From the logical viewpoint its ok, but i want to test this usecase :-)
I wanted to know, how the service is reacting, if i am giving this kind of food.

Via postman it is working to sent this body as it is..
May you have some idea. Else i would open a bug in karate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's invalid JSON.

You have a solution here, use a string or `text`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75376033/143475

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014394/143475